# Suppress select open on button click within same form field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form field that contains a select and a button to the right. The idea is that the user can click the 'add' button to add an option to the select. The problem is that when clicking the 'add' button it will open both my dialog and the select options, with the select options overlaying my dialog. I would like to only open the dialog on 'add' button click. How do I suppress the select open?

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-placeholder>Search reports</mat-placeholder>
      <mat-select #mySelect>
      <mat-option>Cat</mat-option>
      <mat-option>Dog</mat-option>
      <mat-option>Bird</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
      <button mat-buttons matSuffix mat-stroked-button aria-label="add" (click)="mySelect.close(); alert('open a dialog')">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

The following example shows that clicking the button opens the select, when it shouldn't?

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfxvb6)

--EDIT--
@jal_a has provided an answer in the comments. The solution is to add event.stopPropagation()

```
<button mat-buttons matSuffix mat-stroked-button aria-label="add" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); alert('open a dialog')">
```

[Stackblitz - Fixed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t9xkml)

Comment: Have you tried moving the button out of `mat-form-field`?

Comment: @jal_a, yes moving it out works, but having it in the mat-form-field right aligns the button. I could likely add my own container and place them on the same line; however, it would much easier to layout out as as.

Comment: Then `event.stopPropagation()` on click event should do it.

Comment: @jal_a, that works great. If you write up an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @jal I literally just did the opposite! Moved a button INTO a mat-form-field because it has a tonne of unwanted padding now that appearance="standard" is no longer present in Angular 15 material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the original post and in comments the short answer is `event.stopPropagation()` on the click event of the button to stop the event from bubbling up to the `mat-form-field`.

I also wanted to add how click event on `mat-form-field` opens the `mat-select` component.

`mat-form-field` component is designed to wrap form field controls such as `mat-select` and as a wrapper, for the convenience of the user, when clicked it simulates a click event on the child form control, which it is wrapping.

The way it works is that `mat-select` implements an abstract class `MatFormFieldControl` which has a method `onContainerClick`. What `mat-form-field` does is that it has a reference to its child form control and when clicked it checks if the child control implements the `onContainerClick` method and if so it simply invokes the method. Hence focusing and opening the `mat-select` in this case even when the click event was not triggered on the select form control.